# Visual Studio Meta File name Issue for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I am trying to save my XAML files normally in my project in my visual studio but this pop up comes every time. I tried to clean build and check, uncheck the configuration settings and build again. Same issue. But i have no issues in deploying in devices or build the project. Any Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You may want to use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to determine what meta file it doesn't found.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For now it's working fine as I cleaned my %temp% folder, restarted my visual studio and rebuild it. but the tool is pretty handy. thanks